# Openvpn Server multiple Certs

Tags: openvpn

We have OpenVPN clients with CA-Certificates from an old and a new authority.

We can't change them all at once.

The clients are verifying the certificate presented by the server.

Is it possible to sign the server certificate with the old and new CA? Is there another way that both old and new clients can connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506068/can-a-ssl-certificate-be-signed-by-multiple-certificate-authorities) at StackOverflow and [instruction](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Using_Certificate_Chains) about how to use multiple CAs (stacked certificates).

Another way is to run two OpenVPN instances on the same host, providing them with different ports and certificates signed by different CAs.

Comment: Merlin, thank you for your reply. This is what I was looking for. I can't use stacked certificates because then I would have to modify all client CA-files. I'll use two OpenVPN instances.